# How to change google cloud VM instances local IP?

Tags: networking, cassandra, ip, cloud, local

I want to run multi node Cassandra over a cluster using google cloud, but all of VM instances already have got local IP of 127.0.0.1 and i can't connect nodes. I need them to have different IP's. Could somebody help please?
This is 'ifconfig' on one node:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb6nR.png)
on this node i have determined rpc_address and listen_address as 10.142.0.6; and on the other node, it's IP.
also i have determied this node as seed node in configuration. 
When i start Cassandra service and i want to check it's status using 'nodetool status' i get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrYqQ.png)
I also tried to change JVM_OPTS to "$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost" in cassandra-env.sh but still can't connect.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is loopback IP, not "LAN local IP" which can be used to "connect nodes". Can you attach some screenshot of the VM instance IP information?

Comment: @shaochuancs thanks for your attention. i appended some info that can give a better realization.

Answer (score 0):

I found out! it was due to disability of IP-Forwarding in the setting. It should have been activated in the instance creation time!